# How To Recurisve JSON file without any loop (like:for,while,etc) in Python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, recursion

I'm confuse how to create recursive function to print JSON file without any loops in Python3.

So i have home work from my college, the subject is about recursion in function, the lecturer told me to to use recursion only instead of loops.

My json file in Category.json is:

```
 [{'catId': 1, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Buku & Bangunan'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Buku Codes & Standar'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Buku Dekorasi & Ornamen'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Buku Desain Dapur'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 5, 'name': 'Buku Desain Kamar'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 6, 'name': 'Buku Desain Ruang Keluarga'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 7, 'name': 'Buku Desain Ruang Tamu'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 8, 'name': 'Buku Desain Rumah'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 9, 'name': 'Buku Interior & Eksterior'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 10, 'name': 'Buku Metode & Material Bangunan'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 11, 'name': 'Buku Taman'},
 {'catId': 2, 'id': 12, 'name': 'Persiapan Tes CPNS'},
 {'catId': 2, 'id': 13, 'name': 'Persiapan Tes TOELF & IELTS'},
 {'catId': 2, 'id': 14, 'name': 'Persiapan TPA & Psikotest'},
 {'catId': 3, 'id': 15, 'name': 'Buku Aktivitas'},
 {'catId': 3, 'id': 16, 'name': 'Buku Cerita Anak'},
 {'catId': 3, 'id': 17, 'name': 'Buku Dongeng'},
 {'catId': 3, 'id': 18, 'name': 'Buku Dunia Pengetahuan'},
 {'catId': 3, 'id': 19, 'name': 'Buku Fabel'}]
```

My python code is:

```
import json

def showData(file):
    file_json = open(file)
    data = json.loads(file_json.read())

    return data

print(showData("Category.json"))
```

I'm not finishing my code because i'm still confuse how to do recursion without loops.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to use `recursion` just to print a JSON file instead of `iterations(for, while).`

This is how you print your data using **Recursion**.

```
d = [{'catId': 1, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Buku & Bangunan'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Buku Codes & Standar'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Buku Dekorasi & Ornamen'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Buku Desain Dapur'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 5, 'name': 'Buku Desain Kamar'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 6, 'name': 'Buku Desain Ruang Keluarga'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 7, 'name': 'Buku Desain Ruang Tamu'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 8, 'name': 'Buku Desain Rumah'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 9, 'name': 'Buku Interior & Eksterior'},
 {'catId': 1, 'id': 10, 'name': 'Buku Metode & Material Bangunan'}]

# Recursive Code
def print_json(j):
    # Base condition
    if len(j) == 0:
        return
    # Print the first item of j
    print(j[0])
    # Call the same function on j[1:]
    # Skipping the first item of j in every call
    print_json(j[1:])
    
print_json(d)
```

```
{'catId': 1, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Buku & Bangunan'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Buku Codes & Standar'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Buku Dekorasi & Ornamen'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 4, 'name': 'Buku Desain Dapur'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 5, 'name': 'Buku Desain Kamar'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 6, 'name': 'Buku Desain Ruang Keluarga'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 7, 'name': 'Buku Desain Ruang Tamu'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 8, 'name': 'Buku Desain Rumah'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 9, 'name': 'Buku Interior & Eksterior'}
{'catId': 1, 'id': 10, 'name': 'Buku Metode & Material Bangunan'}
```

*Do you know that Recursion uses something called as a Recursion Stack internally ?*

> That's some extra space overhead with recursive codes.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if I understand the question correctly. Do you want to print each dictionary using a different print statement?

From my understanding, you are trying to do something complicated for something really simple. Since you don’t have nested data, you could make a recursion by passing your entire list in a recursive function, then only printing the first element and passing the rest of the list back again into the recursive function.

```
def recursive_print(datas):
    print(datas[0])

    if len(datas) > 1:
        recursive_print(datas[1:])
```

Re-state your question I misunderstood your problem.